# Set an 'int' in one event and use it in another event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, int

I'm making a little something in Windows Form (C# Visual Studio)
But I need to know how I can set an int and then to use it in another event. For example, :

```
private void BtnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int yes = 1;
    int no = 0;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    if (yes == 1) {
        //EVENT
 }
}
```

When I do this I get some errors. Can anyone help me with this? Or just tell me how to do something like this using a different technique?

Comment: define `yes` as global variable. outside method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to use a field for this:

```
private int _yes;
private void BtnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _yes = 1;
    int no = 0;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
    if (_yes == 1) {
        //EVENT
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot in all my projects :)

Answer (score 2):

The variable "yes" you are declaring is only visible in the scope of the method. By making it a field of class, this would make it visible to all methods in the class (when private).

```
class YourClass
{
    private int yes = 1;
    private int no = 0;

    private void BtnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove the type declaration here to use the class field instead. If you leave the type declaration, the variable here will be used instead of the class field.
        yes = 1;
        no = 0;

        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (yes == 1) {
        //EVENT
        }
    }
}
```